# How to play a live fmp4 stream from web api result

Tags: python-3.x, client, http-live-streaming, fmp4

I have a sample script I am working on that can receive an fmp4 stream or an mpd xml response from an HTTP server. I can retrieve the mpd data with requests.get and it comes back no worries. If I use requests.get with stream = True for the fmp4 the script just hangs - I guess it is receiving the stream and it never ends.

What I would like to do is to take the fmp4 stream or the mpd xml data and be able to display the stream to someone watching. The preference is to work with the fmp4 stream rather than the mpd file if possible but either will do in the end.

Is there a way in Python 3.8 to do this? Display the video stream that is. If so, how?

The GET url looks like this:

```
apiURL = 'media'                                     #The API method path

PARAMS = {'session':session,                         #set the parameters
          'cameraId':cameraID,
          'format':'mpd',                           #change to fmp4 / mpd
          'frames':'all',
          'max_gap':'P0Y0M0DT0H1M0S',
          'media':'video',
          'quality':'high',
          't':'live'}

live = requests.Session()
feed = live.get(baseURL + apiURL,
                params = PARAMS,
                verify = False,
                stream = True)
```

*** The baseURL is just https://localhost:8443/api/

*** The format parameter is where you choose the fmp4 or mpd as output from the request

Any help would be appreciated. I have had a look at using VLC and FFMPEG to handle the output but I am not having any success.

Cheers

The Frog